# It's possible to have a git branch aligned with main, but with specific content overriding main's?

Tags: git

Let's say there is a product used by different customers, and each customer has its logo file.

I would like to have different git branches with the customer logo, but every commit in main   should be present in the customer branch, except for some specified files.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just create the branches from main.. ?

Comment: The only way to do this would be to continuously rebase each of those branches onto main, or merge main into those branches. In my opinion you should not do this for just a logo file, that's a deployment thing where you would take the single branch + a list of logos and combine them to produce all the shippables for all your customers. Don't store these as branches in git.

Answer (score 1):

Branches (branch *names*), in Git, are irrelevant.  Only *commits* matter.

Branch names are used to find commits, so in that sense, branch names matter.  But it's really the commits that matter.  The names are just signposts saying *there is a commit here, if you want it*.

Commits are also used to find commits: each commit finds one earlier commit.  Or, more precisely, any one given commit finds zero-or-more earlier commits, but most commits find exactly one earlier commit.

The situation you describe, then, looks like this:

```
               I   <-- customer1
              /
              | J   <-- customer2
              |/
... <-F <-G <-H   <--main
              |\
              | K   <-- customer3
              \
               L   <-- customer4
```

Each of the "customer" branch commits (`I`, `J`, `K`, and `L` here) remembers, as its parent, commit `H`: the *last* commit on `main`.  Each stores as its snapshot the same snapshot as `main` plus the logo file(s).

Should you make a new `main` commit, you'll now have to copy each "customer" commit to a new and improved "customer commit":

```
               I   <-- customer1
              /
              | J   <-- customer2
              |/
... <-F <-G <-H <-N   <--main
              |\
              | K   <-- customer3
              \
               L   <-- customer4
```

No commit can ever be *changed*, so existing `I`, `J`, `K`, and `L` are stuck the way they are, but you can use `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick` to copy `I` to `I'` whose difference from `I` is that its parent is `N` and its snapshot is `N`-plus-logo-files, etc.  Repeat for every customer.

(**This is not the way to go** but it is what you asked for.  The way to go is to have a build process that *combines* the customer files with the latest `main`-branch files.  The customer files can be kept in separate, orphan branches.)